# LISP function to remove nils

Tags: function, lisp

I want to write a function in LISP that will completely remove all NILS in a list. The list may be nested, meaning it can contain other lists inside. For example the list '((state L L L L) NIL (state L L R L) NIL) should be tranformed into '((STATE L L L L) (STATE L L R L)).

Comment: Can there be `NIL`s in the sublists?  If yes, should they also be removed?  If yes, how deep can the nesting go?

Answer (score 10):

```
(defun remove-nil-recursively (x)
  (if (listp x)
    (mapcar #'remove-nil-recursively
            (remove nil x))
    x))
```

Works for your example:

```
[1]> (remove-nil-recursively '((state L L L L) NIL (state L L R L) NIL))
((STATE L L L L) (STATE L L R L))
```

And with nested lists:

```
[2]> (remove-nil-recursively '(NIL (state L L nil R L) NIL))
((STATE L L R L))
```

But watch out:

```
[3]> (remove-nil-recursively '(NIL (state L L (nil) R L) NIL))
((STATE L L NIL R L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Paul Graham calls this function (recurring into sublists remove-if) "prune" in [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html), p. 49. It is one of the utility functions.

```
(defun prune (test tree)
  (labels ((rec (tree acc)
              (cond
               ((null tree) (nreverse acc))
               ((consp (car tree))
                (rec (cdr tree)
                     (cons (rec (car tree) nil) acc)))
               (t (rec (cdr tree)
                       (if (funcall test (car tree))
                           acc
                         (cons (car tree) acc)))))))
    (rec tree nil)))

(prune #'evenp '(1 2 (3 (4 5) 6) 7 8 (9)))
(1 (3 (5)) 7 (9))
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic function in the style of `remove-if`:

```
(defun remove-all (predic seq &optional res)
  (if (null seq)
      (reverse res)
      (cond ((and (not (null (car seq))) (listp (car seq)))
             (remove-all predic (cdr seq)
                         (cons (remove-all predic (car seq)) res)))
            ((funcall predic (car seq))
             (remove-all predic (cdr seq) res))
            (t (remove-all predic (cdr seq) (cons (car seq) res))))))
```

Examples:

```
>  (remove-all #'null (list 1 2 'nil 3))
=> (1 2 3)
>  (remove-all #'null (list 1 2 'nil '(4 5 nil 6) 3))
=> (1 2 (4 5 6) 3)
>  (remove-all #'(lambda (x) (oddp x)) '(1 2 (3 4) 5 6 (7 8 (9 10))))
=> (2 (4) 6 (8 (10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun remove-if-nil (list) (remove-if-not 'identity list))
```

remove-if-not takes a predicate and a list, and removes all the items in the list that do not satisfy the predicate, that is, that return nil when evaluated in the predicate. identity, as you can guess, returns exactly the same thing it takes, so (remove-if-not 'identity list) removes every element in list that is nil.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I added a brief explanation, I hope it helps to clarify.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle nested lists as the question stated.